# Content type with taxonomy in single exposed filter

Tags: 7, nodes, views

i want to a single exposed filter with content types and taxonomy for a single content type,
like i have 3 content types Parts,Tools,Equipments and have a taxonomy for parts with terms Hardware,Instruments and components, now i want a views exposed filter containing both of the them to filter.
Is there any method to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

[Finder](https://drupal.org/project/finder) module will filter both of the fields, You can select taxonomy term, node title, body, fields, ..etc to perform the search.

> There are many ways to put together finder's functionality to get the
>   sort of search form you need. There are also many hooks and theme
>   functions allowing full customization of finder's output.

It is used for these purposes:

```
As a search tool to find a group of nodes or users.
As a way to navigate to a specific node or user page that matches criteria.
As an alternative to exposed filters for a Views module display.
```